# Convert html/css to google doc and keep styles as close as possible

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Right now I am able to create a new text/html document and add some html to it with google drive API. That part looks like this:

```
  await drive.files.create({

    //request body has html/text mime type
    
    requestBody: body.requestBody,
    fields: 'id',
  }, async function (err: any, file: any) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
    
      //update adds media with html content
    
      await drive.files.update({
        fileId: file.data.id,
        media: body.media,
      });
    }
```

After that I am converting the file to a google doc like this but some of the formatting is lost.

```
      await drive.files.copy(
        {
          fileId:  file.data.id,
          requestBody: { 
            name:  file.data.name,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
          }
        }
     
      );
```

The formatting will keep h1 and h2 etc, making the headings bold and different sizes, but all other formatting is lost.

I do not need the formatting to be perfect, but I need it to be close. Is there any work around for this?

Maybe re-add styles after the document is converted, or create a template or something like that?

Or something else I am missing?

The required formatting will be simple, things like centering and sizing images, font sizes, etc.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use the google docs api instead.   Your making your life harder doing it this way.  If you really want to do it like this then covert it in the create itself dont bother with the copy its just an extra unneed step

Comment: hi, you're right that copy was unneeded. With google docs api, won't I need to format everything manually? Maybe that's the only way, but I already have formatting in another place with html/css. I was hoping to have one codebase if possible.

Comment: I thought there would be a way to have google docs keep more of the formatting from html/css